# logical issue in sql query

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm asked to create an application for employees attendance, and I have a logical problem:

I have `emp` table with `id` and `name`, the second table is `attendance` with `id`, `empid`, `date`, `check` (true or false), `id` is the PK.

There will be a form to submit each employee attendance by it self. The user will have a form with the name of employee with a drop down box populated with all employees and a date input text to add the date, and finally yes or no drop down box. My problem is the user can enter 1 or more attendance for the same date and the same employee, which might end with an employee with 40 days attendance in one month.

I'm using google apps engine with datastore, so, any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: If you are using the datastore, why are you asking about SQL? The datastore does not support SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a unique key (empid, date).
It works like a second primary key - does not alow duplicates.

Comment: is that possible with datastore ?

Comment: I don't know what is `google apps engine with datastore`, but ANSI SQL supports it. See examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: Datastore doesn't natively support unique keys like that. Please don't assume that Datastore is SQL, it isn't.

Comment: The OP raise an issue with "SQL query". See the question title :)